# how to wrap text of selectfield option in sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'am trying to display Sencha Touch 2 `selectfield` with very long option text but text gets truncated with Ellipsis, like `Very long option t...`.

How to display couple lines in one option?

Code:

```
{
xtype: 'selectfield',
options:[
    {
       text: 'Very long option I wish to splint into two separate lines',
       value: 0
     },
    {
       text: 'Another very long option I wish to splint into two separate lines', 
       value: 1
    }
 ]
}
```

I've tried using `\n` and `<br/>` but is not working.

Comment: You might have to apply `white-space: pre-wrap  !important;` to `.x-list-label`

Comment: Thank you very much! It is work in browser but not on android phone and works only for picker not for select list. I think, I have to apply `white-space: pre-wrap !important;` to other x-elements. So'm working around...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 3 two ways to do this.

1. use `labelWrap` config option set to true.
   This will avoid truncating text that appears on `selectfield` initially. Later when you tap on selectfield; you've two choices. Using   `picker` or `list`. `picker` will be used only if you set it to true in `usePicker` config. If you are on tablet, desktop or mobile default `list` will be shown containing options. Using `labelWrap` config will not be usefull if options are displayed in `list` after tap on selectfield.
2. Use following CSS override to avoid truncating.

   ```
   .x-list-item-label{
       height: 100% !important;
    }
    .x-list-label{
       white-space: pre-wrap !important;
    }
   ```

   This override along with above mentioned `labelWrap` config set to true will make both `list` and `selectfield` display whole text neatly. But this will override styles that may affect appearance of other lists in your app.
3. Third approach that can be is to override `Ext.field.Select` and create custom select field. In this style, you need to just override following method - `getTabletPicker` that generated the list displayed on tap of selectfield. Code from ST source is as fallows -

   ```
   getTabletPicker: function() {
   var config = this.getDefaultTabletPickerConfig();

   if (!this.listPanel) {
       this.listPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', Ext.apply({
           centered: true,
           modal: true,
           cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'select-overlay',
           layout: 'fit',
           hideOnMaskTap: true,
           items: {
               xtype: 'list',
               store: this.getStore(),
               itemTpl: '<span class="x-list-label">{' + this.getDisplayField() + ':htmlEncode}</span>',
               listeners: {
                   select : this.onListSelect,
                   itemtap: this.onListTap,
                   scope  : this
               }
           }
       }, config));
   }

   return this.listPanel;
   }
   ```

   Check out the line `itemTpl` and `cls` config. Here both options set styles that are defined for `list`. These will decide the appearance of `list` displayed on tap of selectfield. This approach might sound dirty. But it's useful, if you want to make some drastic changes in appearance and behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! Third method is better in my case.**Please, guys, finger up for SachinG's answer** (unfortunately, I am newbie on stack so I can't do that now)