# selectfield with couple lines sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm try to put long option into Sencha Touch 2 `selectfield` 
[It is work only for picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517150/how-to-wrap-text-of-selectfield-option-in-sencha-touch-2) but I need to display whole option text inside `selectfield` too. Let me explain with pictures. I have [image] 
I want (painted in GIMP) [image]
I tried to increase height of `selectfield` and apply `white-space: pre-wrap !important;` but text still truncated...

Comment: it's a shame that when I tried setting `labelWrap:true` for selectfield. It was working well when I answered your other question. And that I clearly remember. But it's not working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it!
I looked through Sencha-2.2 sources and found that `selectfield` extended from the `textfield`. I copied `selectfield` source in my own class `areaselectfield` and changed there only two lines:

```
extend: 'Ext.field.TextArea',
xtype: 'areaselectfield'
```

Maybe there is simpler way but it works